# How to output T? not Nullable<T> in EF Reverse Engineer Code First?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, t4

The "Reverse Engineer Code First" functionality of [Entity Framework Power Tools, Beta 2](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d) is very good and I am working on customising the Reverse Engineer Templates.

In Entity.tt, take a look at the following line (line breaks introduced):

```
<#= Accessibility.ForProperty(property) #> 
<#= code.Escape(property.TypeUsage) #> 
<#= code.Escape(property) #> 
{ get; set; }
```

For a database column named "SomeDate" of type datetime, you will have the following code outputted:

```
public Nullable<System.DateTime> SomeDate { get; set; }
```

How can I modify the Entity.tt code to produce this instead:

```
public DateTime? SomeDate { get; set; }
```

Thank you,

R.

Comment: Why do you want to, they are the same thing...

Comment: ReSharper and StyleCop. Also, I have never, ever written Nullable<System.DateTime> and would prefer my tools don't either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As podiluska mentioned, you need to edit EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude (you can see that this is imported by Entity.tt if you follow the "Customize Reverse Engineer Templates" [instructions  here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj593170))

On my machine it is here:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\Templates\Includes

Around line 127, replace

```
return String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Nullable<{0}>", typeName);
```

With

```
return String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}?", typeName);
```

**Make sure you test this. It worked fine for me, but I can't guarantee that it will work for all nullable types. Any comments would be appreciated and I will edit this post as appropriate**

Comment: Seems good but I'm on another project now so who knows when I might stress it properly. But I'll accept.

Comment: I'm not able to modify it at all, it won't let me edit it if I try to save.

Comment: What is the message? Do you have edit permissions on the directory and file? Try createing a new file in the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

`code` is a `CodeGenerationTools`, contained in `EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude`

If you want to change the behaviour of `Escape`, then you can edit it in there